# Perform Group Action using MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, graph-algorithm, bigdata

I am trying to implement a sequential Graph Algorithm in MapReduce.

In this I have to perform [Group Action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action). Please visit Wikipedia to understand what is a Group action.

Suppose I have groups {a1,a2,a3},{b1,b2,b3},{c1,c2,c3}. Let us name this group by G1,G2,G2. Based on group action, G1 can split G2 or G3. Similar for G2 and G3 also. 
I have to determine if a group Gi can split Gj and then output the split for all groups.
It seems that I have to do (nP2) permutations. *each group compared to all others*
Suppose the input is the list of groups.
So, how can we do this type of permutation based calculation and also do this splits using MapReduce.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a classic mapreduce scenario because if I understand correctly you have no keys/values here. If I still wanted to use mapreduce I would do it this way:

1. Preprocess the groups - create the set which consists of all the Gi,Gj pairs for all i,j.
   {A∈P | P is the power set of the set of the groups ∧ |A|=2}.
   Now you have the input arranged such that every map task can receive 2 groups as its input.
2. The mapper in your job will have the method that decides if Gi can split Gj - 
   emit the split if it exists.
3. No reducer is needed

Comment: However, creating nP2 groups will be huge tasks(say for n=5000). How to do it in parallel using MapRed?